# Shimano Revo shifter does not shift

Tags: maintenance, gears, shifter, mechanical, shifting

I have recently bought a new bicycle and the left Shimano Revo shifter (3 speed) is not shifting, what can I do?

Comment: Take it back to the shop where you bought it and have them adjust the shifter.

Comment: The left revo shifter is normally a friction shifter, so you have to figure out how much to twist it to get to the right chairing by feel. It doesn't "click" into place like an indexed shifter, normally. The right side on the other hand is indexed - it will click into the different cogs in the back.

Comment: There is not enough info in your question to answer it properly - there can be several things to check, so +1 @ Daniel R Hicks.

Answer (score 0):

To really know what is wrong we need more information. But to give you some help:

If you don't know how to re-adjust the gear to shift correctly:
- Clean the derailleur (which pushes your chain to another gear).
- Push the cable back and forth a bit, and if possible, oil it a bit.
If this didn't work and you don't know how to adjust your gears to work correctly, bring it to a bicycle mechanic (such as me!). Because you can't do much more without disassembling the cable.

If you do know how to re-adjust the gear, this works better:
- Disassemble the cable.
- Clean the derailleur, and put some grease on the spring.
- Take out the inner cable, and spray a lot of oil in the outer cable
- Assemble the cable inside the outer cable. Check if the shifter works correctly by pulling the cable and shifting.
- Assemble it al again.

edit: it took me 2 edit's to correctly write 'inside'!

Answer (score 0):

If you have only just purchased the bike it would be within its warranty period. If it is not shifting it could be for a number of reasons but I would take it back and get it fixed free of charge as it is there obligation to fix or exchange it.